# Create a user in a Dockerfile : Option d is ambiguous

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm writing a Dockerfile where I want to create a user and use it instead of `root` user because that's a recommended practice.

I do the following:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
...
```

`docker-compose up` rewards me with the following error message:

```
...    
Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)
ERROR: Service 'webapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c adduser -D myuser' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

That `-d` flag if often used (e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@DahlitzF/run-python-applications-as-non-root-user-in-docker-containers-by-example-cba46a0ff384)) to create a user in a dockerfile but I can't figure out what it is supposed to be, `disabled-password` ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `RUN adduser --disabled-login myuser` (or --disabled-password)

Answer (score 1):

You actually should use `useradd` instead of `adduser`....

For example:

```bash
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash worker
```

The reason you want to use `useradd` is because it's *NOT* an interactive prompt asking you for questions and user input.

Also, `adduser` (Perl script) is basically a wrapper around `useradd` command.

**Conclusion**: When you want to create a new user in an *automated fashion*, you really want to use **`useradd`**.

Comment: can you explain why ?

Comment: @snoobdogg Sorry, I indeed forgot that. It's now added!

Answer (score -3):

- Your `docker-compose up` is failing in the build step. When docker is trying to build the image, it encounters an error at line `RUN adduser -D myuser`
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd . You can read the manual what the flags mean.
- Remove `-D` flag, i.e, change the command to `RUN adduser myuser`, new user will be added and build will be able to proceed to next step.
- If you want to change defaults of `adduser`, you can read use the flags in the docs shared above.

Comment: So again `useradd` or `adduser` is not the same.